# PHP cookies redirect issue

Tags: php, redirect, cookies

I'm not exactly sure what the problem is but the cookies aren't available for subdomains. Is there any way around this, or is there a better way to set the cookies domain? Thanks!

```
<?php 
ini_set("session.cookie_domain", ".example.com"); 

// Set cookie and redirect when user change city 
if( isset($_POST['city']) && $_POST['city'] != '' ){ 
$cookie_expire = time() + 50400;  
setcookie('city', $_POST['city'], $cookie_expire, '/'); 

header("Location: http://".$_POST["city"].".example.com"); 
die(); 
} 

// Redirect if user selected default city 
if (isset($_COOKIE["city"])) { 
$subdomain = array_shift(explode(".",$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])); 

if ($_COOKIE["city"] != $subdomain) { 
    header("Location: http://".$_COOKIE["city"].".example.com"); 
    die(); 
} 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using $domain parameter of setcookie.

```
setcookie('city', $_POST['city'], $cookie_expire, '/', '.example.com'); // With leading dot for old browsers
```

See here:
http://php.net/setcookie

Comment: Ok, missed first line in your example.
Could you give more information? Domains, or demo?
What browser do you use to check?

Comment: What do you mean by first line? Sorry my site is not viewable for public. I have tested with IE, Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: I mean, I missed "ini_set" line.
Your code is OK, so there might be another problem in your environment.

Comment: Where should I put it? Can you give me the whole script? Thanks!

Comment: I have tested the server by using some testing script and it is working.

Comment: As I said, your code should work. There might be a problem with another component, like server or php config.

Answer (score 0):

Check the path on the cookie if the cookie path is http://www.example.com/
and you redirect to http://www.example.com ( note the lack of a trailing / ) some browsers will drop the cookies - in my experience.